# How to pass properties to icons with Storybook and React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, storybook

How do I pass props (like colors and size) to an svg with storybook and react?.
My code is looking like this:

```
const ICONS = { icon: <Icon />, icon2: <Icon2 /> };
// This icons are simple svg files of an icon.
const noIcon = undefined;
export default {
  title: "Components/Button",
  component: Button,
  argTypes: {
    handleClick: { action: "handleClick" },
    icon: {
      control: {
        type: "select",
        options: [undefined, ...Object.keys(ICONS)],
      },
    },
  },
};

const Template = ({ iconName, ...rest }) => {
  const icon = ICONS[iconName];
  return <Button icon={icon} {...rest} />;
};
```

Button.js is this code:

```
<button
      onClick={handleClick}
      style={style}
      className={`button ${size === "m" ? "button-m" : "button-s"}`}
      disabled={disabled}
    >
      <div>{icon}</div>
      <span
        style={styleButton}
        className={size === "m" ? "button-content-m" : "button-content-s"}
      >
        {content}
      </span>
    </button>
```

Currently, I can pass the object with icons, but I don't know how to change colors and sizes of the svg.

I'm expecting to find a way to change properties of the icons